# how can I make result of ARRAY_AGG() function json parsable

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, sql-function

I have a query that selects the rows from joined table as an array using ARRAY_AGG() function.

```
select 
    entity_number, 
    ARRAY_AGG('{"property_id":"'||property_id||'","value":"'||value||'"}') entity_properties from entities
join entity_properties
on entities.id = entity_properties.entity_id
where entities.id in (
    select entity_id from entity_properties 
    where value = '6258006d824a25dabdb39a79.pdf'
)
group by entities.id;
```

what I get is:

```
[
    {
        "entity_number":"P1718238009-1",
        "entity_properties":"[
            \"{\"property_id\":\"006109cd-a100-437c-a683-f13413b448e6\",\"value\":\"Rozilik berildi\"}\",
            \"{\"property_id\":\"010f5e23-d66f-4414-b54b-9647afc6762b\",\"value\":\"6258006d824a25dabdb39a79.pdf\"}\",
            \"{\"property_id\":\"0a01904e-1ca0-40ef-bbe1-c90eaddea3fc\",\"value\":\"6260c9e9b06e4c2cc492c470_2634467.pdf\"}\"
        ]"
    }
]
```

As you can see, it is not json parsable

To parse `entity_properties` as array of objects I need the data in this format

```
[
    {
        "entity_number":"P1718238009-1",
        "entity_properties":[
            {"property_id":"006109cd-a100-437c-a683-f13413b448e6","value":"Rozilik berildi"},
            {"property_id":"010f5e23-d66f-4414-b54b-9647afc6762b","value":"6258006d824a25dabdb39a79.pdf"},
            {"property_id":"0a01904e-1ca0-40ef-bbe1-c90eaddea3fc","value":"6260c9e9b06e4c2cc492c470_2634467.pdf"}
        ]
    }
]
```

Can I achieve what I want with `ARRAY_AGG()`? How?

If not, what approach should I take?

Comment: your original query should be `group by 1`?

Comment: The `ARRAY_AGG` is not the *cause* of the *escaping*. You make some additional processing to build the json that introduces the escaping. As the last rescue - simple use *replace*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [json_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html) and [json_build_object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) function

like this:

```
select 
    entity_number, 
    json_agg(json_build_object('property_id', property_id, 'value', value)) entity_properties from entities
join entity_properties
on entities.id = entity_properties.entity_id
where entities.id in (
    select entity_id from entity_properties 
    where value = '6258006d824a25dabdb39a79.pdf'
)
group by entities.id;
```

Comment: yes, sorry for the typo, double quotes are for case-sensitive names. your edit is already updated.

Answer (score 0):

Using a simplified sample data this query provides the first step of the aggregation

```
with tab as (
select * from (values
 (1,'a','x'),
 (1,'b','y'),
 (2,'c','z')
) tab(entity_number,property_id,value)
) 
select 
   entity_number,
   json_agg( json_build_object('property_id', property_id, 'value', value)) entity_properties 
from tab
group by 1
;

entity_number|entity_properties                                                           |
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
            1|[{"property_id" : "a", "value" : "x"}, {"property_id" : "b", "value" : "y"}]|
            2|[{"property_id" : "c", "value" : "z"}]
```

Additional aggregation returns the final json array

```
with tab as (
select * from (values
 (1,'a','x'),
 (1,'b','y'),
 (2,'c','z')
) tab(entity_number,property_id,value)
),
tab2 as (
select 
   entity_number,
   json_agg( json_build_object('property_id', property_id, 'value', value)) entity_properties 
from tab
group by 1
)
select 
 json_agg(
  json_build_object(
   'entity_number',
   entity_number,
   'entity_properties',
   entity_properties
  )
 ) 
from tab2

 [
    {
        "entity_number": 1,
        "entity_properties": [
            {
                "value": "x",
                "property_id": "a"
            },
            {
                "value": "y",
                "property_id": "b"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "entity_number": 2,
        "entity_properties": [
            {
                "value": "z",
                "property_id": "c"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Note that I used `jsonb_pretty` to format the output.